# Should I code with no servlets?

Tags: jsp, servlets, jstl, taglib

I am working on a study project. There is JDBC. 
I do know that JSP translates to a servlet. I see that I can avoid almost all the servlets using JSP taglibs, EL...  Should I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: no.

JSP is for the view, and the view layer should be as dumb as possible.

Servlets (or other framework) are for marshalling between the web layer and the business layer.

The business layer (includes several buzzwords) is where the bulk of application logic should live.

Separation makes testing and extension substantially easier.